# How to place regex pattern in Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, regex

My program reads csv line from a file.

```
300,"fd,s"ds,10000
```

I would like the result like below:

```
300
fd,sds
10000
```

This pattern works, but how do I place it in javascript function to get result like above?
Unable to adjust it in split function.

```
var str = '300,"fd,s"ds,10000';
 var mySplits = str.split('"[^"]*"|[^,]+'); 
 console.log(mySplits[1]);
```

Comment: CSV parsing is much harder than it looks. [Use a robust, mature library](https://www.papaparse.com/). Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid CSV. Where did the double quote after the `s` go? If it was a delimiter, then why is `ds` still in the same field? If it was not a delimiter, then why is it gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- You did not pass a regex to `split`, but a literal string. In JavaScript, regex literals are not delimited by a quote, but by a forward slash.
- Your regex is intended to match the *content*, while `split` expects an expression that matches the *delimiters*, not the content. You could use `matchAll` to match content.
- The example CSV is invalid as the middle field uses a double quote as delimiter, but there is still content following after the closing quote.
- The rules for parsing CSV format are not that a good fit for regular expressions.

Still, for the purpose of your example, you could use this fix:

```js
var str = '300,"fd,s"ds,10000';
var iter = str.matchAll(/"([^"]*)"([^,]*)|([^,]+)/g);
for (let match of iter) {
    console.log(match[3] || match[1] + match[2]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the exact match for my pattern

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't work, see the array length equal to 1. However, here is what you want:

```js
var str = '300,"fd,s"ds,10000';
var mySplits = str.split('"[^"]*"|[^,]+');
console.log(mySplits.length);// 1

const res = str.match(/^(.*?)(?:,")(.*)"(.*),(.*)$/);
console.log(res[1]);
console.log(res[2] + res[3]);
console.log(res[4]);
```

Comment: Superb, it works,Thank you @8HoLoN